# Is there an upper limit to the magnitude of the derivative of a unit vector?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Suppose I have a unit vector $\boldsymbol{\hat{u}}(t)$ and I take its derivative with respect to time. I then take $\Vert d\boldsymbol{\hat{u}}(t)/dt \Vert$. My question is, because $\boldsymbol{\hat{u}}(t)$ has a magnitude of 1, which is the maximum value of $\Vert d\boldsymbol{\hat{u}}(t)/dt \Vert$. Is there even a unique solution? Can't seem to make much progress on this.

Comment: Interestingly, the unit constraint on $u$ does not constrain the **_magnitude_** of $\frac{du}{dt}$ in any way, but it does constrain its **_direction_**  to be perpendicular to $u.\;$

Answer (score 2):

There is no upper limit to $|{d\mathbf{u}/dt}|$. Consider $\mathbf{u}(t) = (\cos(\omega t), \sin(\omega t)).$ As $t$ grows, $\mathbf{u}$ traces out a path on a unit circle. As you may verify, $|{d\mathbf{u}/dt}| = \omega$, which goes to infinity as $\omega \rightarrow \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

If ${\hat u}(t) = (\sqrt{t}, \sqrt{1-t})$ then $||{\hat u}|| =1$, but
$d{\hat{u}}(t)/dt = (\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}, \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{t}})$ whose norm is unbounded. Is that what you are looking for?